# EF 6 - Cascade Delete on one to many without backreference

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-mapping

I have something like this:

```
public class Gadget {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public int SuperHeroId { get; set; }
}

public class SuperHero {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Gadget> Gadgets { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that while a Gadget is "owned" by a Superhero (and therefore there's an FK in the database), my domain model does not have a hard reference in that direction.

When I delete a superhero I would like to also delete all their gadgets. How would I do this?

My research indicates that if I had that reference it would be something like

```
mapping.Entity<SuperHero>()
  .HasMany(x => x.Gadgets)
  .WithRequired(x => x.SuperHero) //this is the part I can't do
  .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

but as noted, that doesn't work with my domain model.

Comment: can you not create a hard reference?

Comment: No - In my case, that would be bad design.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
mapping.Entity<SuperHero>()   
       .HasMany(x => x.Gadgets)
       .WithRequired() //use the override that doesn't 
                       //specify a navigation property             
       .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696502(v=vs.113).aspx

> Configures the relationship to be optional:required without a
>   navigation property on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: Apparently `WithRequired()`  was dropped in ef core transition. See [question 38381829](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381829/8267825).